# SD card has 81% free space but says insufficient space for App2SD (native, Huawei Honor 4X)

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory, huawei

I have downloaded OLX app and presently it is in internal memory. 
When I try to move this app to SD card it says "Insufficient space. Can't move to SD card". Please help. 
I am using Huawei Honor 4X handset now.

Comment: Not enough info. If app data takes more than 81% of your sd card space then there will be not enough space on sd card.

Comment: SD card has nothing to do with the "insufficient storage" error. Please take a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details – which also should get you started with solving your issue. Fingers crossed!

Comment: How about some specifics. What is the size of your SD?

Comment: If your device is rooted, better use Link2SD.. Make a partition on your SD card and then try to move the apps..(Backup all data before partition)..

Comment: How do I make a partition in SD card. SD card is of 32 GB.

Comment: 23 GB space available in SD card and the size of app want to move is just about 18mb

Answer (score 0):

Try to move some small apps from SD card to phone memory, then try moving any apps from phone memory to SD card, as you said Ola, or any other. I did the same when I had that issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cheap cards that are actually hacked - they lie their capacity to the system. I'd suggest you to make a test to check if you didn't get a fake SD card. [This site](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2592/#:%7E:text=Install%20the%20H2testw%20on%20your,capacity%20of%20your%20SD%20card.) recommends you to install [H2testw](https://static.tp-link.com/beta/2021/202105/20210517/h2testw_1.4.zip) in a Windows computer or [SD Insight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.humanlogic.sdi&hl=pt_BR&gl=US) Android app to test the card's properties. Another option for newer Android is 

[True SD Card Capacity & Speed Test: Pro Version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=alan.sdcardsize.paid&hl=pt_BR&gl=US) app.

Unfortunately, cheap SD cards most of the time mean fake SD cards - they often have a much smaller capacity than what they announce (and smaller than all the OS recognizes), causing data corruption when you try to store more data than what those fake cards actually supports - among other problems...